# Solr - Keep Punctuation in Parsed Phrase Query

Tags: solr, solrj

I am working with apache-solr-3.6.0 on windows machine. I would like to search for phrases which contain punctuation marks. Example:

```
"He said: Hi"
```

I tried to escape the punctuation marks using `\` so my url was:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q="He%20said\:%20Hi"&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&debugQuery=true
```

But I discovered that solr trim the punctuation in the parsed query and the result was:

```
<str name="rawquerystring">"He said\: Hi"</str>
<str name="querystring">"He said\: Hi"</str>
<str name="parsedquery">PhraseQuery(text:"he said hi")</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">text:"he said hi"</str>
```

So How could I query a phrase without trimming the punctuation marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my question [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-Keep-Punctuation-in-Parsed-Phrase-Query-td4008977.html).

It seems that the problem was in the fieldtype.
So when I modified my schema to:

```
<field name="text" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

it works. and `text_ws` tokenizer was `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`

Answer (score 0):

What analyzer/tokenizer are you using?

Check the analysis.jsp for the behavior and adjust accordingly.

Comment: How could I adjust analysis.jsp to keep punctuation marks in my phrase query?